# Download Workflow Manager Components Without Web Installer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, workflow-manager

I have spent hours trying to pull together the Workflow Manager installation components for SharePoint 2013 in an environment that doesn't have Internet access. Microsoft in their infinite wisdom seem to think that the web installer is available to every environment.

Where can I download all the Workflow Manager components for offline installation **without** using the Web installer?

Answer (score 1):

You need the internet connection to download the WFM component with web Plateform. You dont need to install it on server, but install it on the pc with internet connection just to download the files.

1. Logon to the machine where you have internet connection and down
   load the web platform installer “WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi” from here
2. Extract the files from “WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi” to a
   folder. There are different ways to extract files from msi. below is
   the example using msiexec utilty.
   Open Command prompt or powershell run as administrator and enter the
   below command:

   msiexec /a  /qb TARETDIR =

Ex:

```
msiexec /a C:\SharePoint\SP2013\Tools\WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\ePoint\SP2013\Tools\wpi
```

- Download Workflow Manager components using WebpiCmd.exe In the
  command prompt or powershell

  Webpicmd /offline /Products:ServiceBus /Path:E:\ServiceBus

  Webpicmd /offline /Products:WorkflowClient /Path:E:\WorkflowClient

  Webpicmd /offline /Products:WorkflowManagerRefresh /Path:E:\WorkflowManagerRefresh
- On the machine with internet access, download the Cumulative Update for Service Bus 1.0 from: 
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36794
- Now move the files to the servers

Source: [SharePoint 2013 – Workflow Manager 1.0 offline download](https://sharepointdeal.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-1-0-offline-download/)

Also read this one: [Installing Workflow Manager Offline](https://content.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2015/7/28/installing-workflow-manager-offline)

Comment: This doesn't work in a scenario where it is not possible to install the Web Platform Installer - for example, onsite at a customer in a Citrix environment the local citrix session has internet access but it is not possible to install software (i.e. the Web Platform Installer)

Comment: you dont need to isntall the web platform rather download and extract it. check the 1st link.

Comment: msiexec requires admin privileges to run. In a citrix session this isn't possible as a normal user.

Comment: i can understand it, now workaround is to download it from personal or non network device.

Comment: Microsoft is so ridiculous